# How to combine Excel file with python? (columnAB+columnC)

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl, xlrd

How to combine Excel file with python? (columnAB+columnC)
I use pandas to combine Excel file.However, it doesn't work.

```
!pip install xlrd
!pip install xlwt
!pip install openpyxl
import xlrd
import xlwt
import openpyxl



import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()

for f in ['MOMO摩天-專品商品名稱購買人數.xls', "MOMO摩天-專品價格.xls"]:
    data = pd.read_excel(f, 'Sheet1')
    data.index = [os.path.basename(f)] 
    df = df.append(data)

df.to_excel('Combine.xls')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert Excel files to two distinct Dataframe and then use this function to merge two Dataframe in one:

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

ex:

```
> df1 = pd.DataFrame({'lkey': ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'foo'],
                    'value': [1, 2, 3, 5]})
> df2 = pd.DataFrame({'rkey': ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'foo'],
                    'value': [5, 6, 7, 8]})
> df1
    lkey value
0   foo      1
1   bar      2
2   baz      3
3   foo      5
> df2
    rkey value
0   foo      5
1   bar      6
2   baz      7
3   foo      8

> df1.merge(df2, left_on='lkey', right_on='rkey')
  lkey  value_x rkey  value_y
0  foo        1  foo        5
1  foo        1  foo        8
2  foo        5  foo        5
3  foo        5  foo        8
4  bar        2  bar        6
5  baz        3  baz        7
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can import an **Excel** file into **Python** using **Pandas** 'read_excel'.

```
import pandas as pd

#Replace - Path where the Excel file is stored\File name.xlsx
#Replace - your Excel sheet name

df = pd.read_excel (r'Path where the Excel file is stored\File name.xlsx', sheet_name='your Excel sheet name')

print (df)
```

**Combine Two Columns in Pandas**.

You can use the following syntax to combine two text columns into one in a pandas DataFrame:

```
#Replace - Column Names with applicable column names 
df['new_column'] = df['column1'] + df['column2']
```

You can export Pandas **DataFrame** to an **Excel** file using **to_excel**

```
#Replace - Path where the exported excel file will be stored\File Name.xlsx
df.to_excel(r'Path where the exported excel file will be stored\File Name.xlsx', index = False)
```

Answer (score 0):

import pandas as pd

```
df1 = pd.read_excel(name1) #if doesn't work, change file format to xlsx
df2 = pd.read_excel(name2)
```

Now use merge or join. For example:

```
df = df1.join(df2)
```